# Keeping only letters and digits in a string

Tags: string, spss, recode

I am recoding some open survey responses in SPSS and am wanting just to keep the usual characters a-z and 1-9

I have done rtrim and ltrim which has worked on the majority, but some strings have trailing spaces remaining, which I am assuming are not actually spaces but are hidden characters.
I have also removed punctuation such as "?" but I imagine there must be a more straightforward way than going through each one.

e.g. I need
"exam'ple!     " or "  exam!!--ple?"
to say "example"

Comment: Does [this link](https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/2013/07/09/quick-spss-tip-cleaning-up-irregular-characters-in-strings/) help?  Essentially use SPSS's PIB format to loop and replace unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will create a new clean field and copy to it only the digits and letters (uppercase or lowercase) from the original field.
Note that I used **15** as the new field width and as the number of iterations in the loop - please change 15 to the actual width of the original field

```
do repeat val=1 to 15.
  compute #i = number(char.substr(OrigField, val, 1), PIB).
  if range(#i, 48, 57) or 
     range(#i, 65, 90) or 
     range(#i, 97, 122)  
       CleanField=concat(rtrim(CleanField), char.substr(OrigField, val, 1)).
end repeat.
exe.
```

See the link suggested by @user45392 to understand how/why this works.
Also see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) for additional values you can add to the loop if you'd like.